# Prevent creation of zero length file for splitmuxsink

Tags: file, gstreamer, rtsp

I use Gstreamer `gst-launch` command to save video from RTSP source into file. The command looks like this:

> `gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://path/to/src ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpmp4vdepay ! mpeg4videoparse ! splitmuxsink location=video%d.avi`

Everything works fine, but when connection can't be established - I get empty file `video0.avi` in result.

Is it possible using some Gstreamer specific element or an option for already existing element in pipeline to disable creation of zero length files?